# Intersection of values of 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays in the form:

```
array1 = [{key1: value1}, {key1: value2}, ...];
array2 = [{key2: value0}, {key2: value2}, ...];
```

where the object keys in both arrays are different, but the values may match. I would like to write some code that gets the intersection between the two arrays where in the above example, it should return: `[value2]`.

I tried using:

```
array1.filter(function(n)) {
    return array2.indexOf(n) != -1;
});
```

but of course I got an empty array because the keys mismatch. Can the above code be modified to ignore the object keys and match only their values?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yep, same key in each array.

Comment: No, sorry that was a syntax typo from my side. I fixed the braces now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var kiran = [];
    var array1 = [{ key1: 'value1' }, { key1: 'value2' }];
    var array2 = [{ key2: 'value0' }, { key2: 'value2' }];
    array1.map(function(item1){
       array2.map(function(item2){
         if(item1.key1 === item2.key2){
           kiran.push(item2.key2);
         }
       })
    })
    console.log(kiran);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about below approach

```js
const array1 = [{ key1: 'value1' }, { key1: 'value2' }];
const array2 = [{ key2: 'value0' }, { key2: 'value2' }];
const result = array1.filter(c => array2.findIndex(x=>x.key2 == c.key1) > -1)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and with a binary value. Then check if the count is equal to three, then take that key as result.

```js
var array1 = [{ key1: 'value1' }, { key1: 'value2' }],
    array2 = [{ key2: 'value0' }, { key2: 'value2' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    incHash = function (i) {
        return function (o) {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                hash[o[k]] = (hash[o[k]] || 0) | 1 << i;
            });
        };
    },
    result;

[array1, array2].forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.forEach(incHash(i));
});
result = Object.keys(hash).filter(function (k) {
    return hash[k] === 3;
});

console.log(result);
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third party library then I suggest **Lodash**. An incredibly usefull utility library.

You can use [_.intersectionWith()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#intersectionWith) funciton to get your task done in one line

```js
        var array1 = [{ key1: 'value1' }, { key1: 'value2' }],
            array2 = [{ key2: 'value0' }, { key2: 'value2' }];
        var intersection = _.map(_.intersectionWith(array1, array2, function(item1,item2){
          return item1.key1 === item2.key2;
        }),'key1');
console.log(intersection);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js">

</script>
```